# Google Analytics API: Get report by tracking id instead of account id

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I'm working with Google analytics API v4 on php using [this example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php). I can get report using account id. But now, I need to get report using tracking id **(UA-xxxxxx-2)** instead of account id. Is it possible?